# Is it possible to dynamically update my for loop object I'm looping through in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Below you can see my code. The question is that for example my *'len(player.hands)'* is equal to 4 and it should go through this loop 4 times. But if in loop I append new object to *'player.hands'* array it still loops just 4 times instead of 5 times. I know that I specified at the beginning of this for loop to go just 4 times, but is there a way to dynamically update it so it automatically goes this one additional time?

```
  # Player turn
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            stop = True
            for hand in range(len(player.hands)):  # I want to update 'player.hands' size in new iteration after appending new 'hand'
                if not player.hands[hand].stay_bool:
                    stop = False
                    player.hands[hand].show()
                    choice = int(input('1. hit\n2. stay\n3. double\n4. split\n'))
    
                    if choice == 1:
                        card = decks.draw_a_card()
                        player.draw_card(hand, card)
                    elif choice == 2:
                        player.hands[hand].stay()
                    elif choice == 3:
                        player.hands[hand].double()
                        card = decks.draw_a_card()
                        player.draw_card(hand, card)
                    elif choice == 4:
                        pass
                        # here I want to append new 'hand' to my 'hands' array
```

Comment: Try using a `while` loop instead and checking the array length at each iteration

Comment: It's pretty bad practice to insert/remove elements within a list while iterating over it at the same time. Maybe create a copy of your list or create a new list while iterating rather than modify the existing one.

Comment: Instead of iterating over `len(player.hands)`, can you iterate over player.hands? If this is object is like an array and you append a new hand at the end then it will work and you could iterate over a new hand entry which was added while iterating over player.hands. 
    
    
Otherwise, you can define the `__iter__` method of your object player.hands object. And within it handle iterating over player.hands